# In Supernatural, why can't just the Winchesters ask for Death's help to defeat the Darkness?

Tags: supernatural

Death once said that he is as old or maybe older than God. He also said that when God dies, he will be the one who will reap him, which sort of implies that he is more powerful than God.

Now, the  Darkness is said to have been defeated merely by Lucifer, an archangel of God. If the Darkness is weaker than Lucifer, who is weaker than God, and God is weaker than Death, why did they ask Lucifer for help instead of Death?

Answer (score 5):

They killed him:

[image: Dean Winchester killing...Death]

<sup>Image from Season 10 Episode 23: "Brother's Keeper"</sup>

The above image depicts Death, implacable as ever, moments after Dean impaled him with his own scythe. The very next image is Death (and the scythe) crumbling to dust:

[image: Death has seen better days]

Although it seems a bit strange that you can kill the literal personification of death, it appears that's exactly what they did. Sam later meets a reaper, named Billie, who tells him as much, in no uncertain terms (emphasis mine):

> **Billie:** I'm not looking to get friendly with **the man who helped gut my boss.**
>
> *[...]*
>
> **Billie:** It's over.
>
> **Sam:** What's over?
>
> **Billie:** You and Dean... Dying and coming back again and again. **The old Death** thought it was funny. But now there's one hard, fast rule in this universe. What lives... dies.
>
> <sup>*Supernatural* Season 11 Episode 2: "Form and Void"</sup>

However, even before they killed him, Death wasn't always on the Brothers' side; it would be entirely within character for him to tell the boys to clean up their own mess.

Comment: Right, I totally forgot about that moment.
I think it kinda makes sense that Death could be killed with his own scythe, just like how an angel can be killed by his own angel dagger.
Thanks :D

Comment: @David Happy to help. Don't forget to accept this answer (by clicking on the checkmark symbol under the voting buttons) if it answered your question to your satisfaction

Comment: I think Supernatural puts too much of a focus on dealing with problems by stabbing them. ;) "Oh, look, here's the sword of Darkness-killing."

Comment: @Adamant I think the ultimate resolution kind of redeemed it. Although I'm left wondering (and not for the first time) where the show can realistically build from there

Answer (score 1):

First of all a few things few seem to focus on. Death never said he could kill god at will. He merely said one day he will reap him and that one day god will die. While this means Death MAY be able to kill god, it's not certain. Maybe when god dies, either from age, injury, or by choice, Death may have to be involved (curious what that would mean now that Death is dead).

However, even if Death can kill God that in no way means he is more powerful or even equal to God. Demons have killed angels, they are certainly not more powerful than them. Lucifer is more powerful than Gabriel but Gabriel seemed pretty sure he had some chance of taking Lucifer down. Death may be in the same league with god just not his equal, and he certainly seems to be above pretty much everything except God, the Darkness, and possibly Godstiel and the arch nyphilum. It's possible he is god's equal in power but not in other ways (like creating universes).
So the whole A>B>C argument doesn't really follow.

It seems that Death may be able to kill anything that can be killed, or at least has a hand in it. It's possible he can't kill the darkness because in killing her the universe will end. I think her not 'knowing' Death has some greater symbolism. Perhaps because she is older than Death she nullifies his powers like Eve and Raphael did to Castile.

Death claims to be at least as old as god so god wouldn't have this ability. She and God can kill each other but it results in the end of the universe. Why Death can kill god but not her, whether death can kill God under what circumstances, and why God can die in the first place when amara can't is pretty much speculation. But it seems that somehow Death and the darkness can't interact and so even if he were still alive I don't think he could fight her.

Comment: This is very unclear. I recommend line breaks as a start.

Answer (score 0):

The Darkness was defeated by God and Lucifer together, and just barely at that. As others have pointed out, your A > B > C argument is also invalid. But since Lucifer was around the first time the Darkness was defeated, the Winchesters needed Lucifer both for his power and his experience, since God was not available.